# How to generate PayPal order pay link to email

Tags: laravel, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to generate PayPal link to email, where user can pay for their order later. I'am using *paypal/rest-api-sdk-php*. For example using this route:

```
Route::get('/order/pay/{hash}', 'Frontend\PaymentController@orderPay')->name('order.pay');
```

My code for payment creation works (see code). When user cancel the payment or payment is unsuccessful, how can I return to the incomplete transaction and try to pay for it again? Should I create new payment everytime user goes to order pay route? Or can I simply identify the incomplete transaction in PayPal and redirect to some(?) PayPal link then?

```
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectURLs;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;

 /*
 * @param  \App\Order  $order
 * @return string
 */
public function createPayment($order)
{
    $transaction = $this->getTransactionByOrderHash($order->hash);

    if ($transaction) {
        if ($transaction->is_refunded) {
            return 'Paymant has already been refunded';
        }
        if ($transaction->is_payed) {
            return 'Paymant has already been payed';
        }
    }

    $price = $order->to_pay;
    $currencyCode = $order->currency->iso_code;

    try {
        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $item = new Item();
        $item
            ->setName(__('invoice.pfa_title'))
            ->setCurrency($currencyCode)
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setSku($order->vs)
            ->setPrice($price);

        $itemList = new ItemList();
        $itemList->setItems([$item]);

        $details = new Details();
        $details
            ->setShipping(0)
            ->setTax(0)
            ->setSubtotal($price);

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount
            ->setCurrency($currencyCode)
            ->setTotal($price)
            ->setDetails($details);

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction
            ->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

        $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls
            ->setReturnUrl(route('paypal.success', $order->hash))
            ->setCancelUrl(route('paypal.cancel'));

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment
            ->setIntent('sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
            ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

        $payment->create($this->apiContext);

        $approvalUrl = $this->getApprovalUrl($payment);

        if ($approvalUrl) {
            session([
                'approval_url' => $approvalUrl,
                'transaction_id' => $payment->getId(),
            ]);
            return 'payment was successful';
        }
    } catch (PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
        return json_decode($ex->getData());
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    return 'payment was unsuccessful';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use the deprecated v1/payments PayPal-PHP-SDK, instead of the current v2/checkout/orders `Checkout-PHP-SDK` ?

In any case, yes you can create a new Payment/Order object everytime the customer attempts a checkout. Just set the invoice_id field to your own same but *unique* invoice/order number for the thing that customer is paying for, so that if the customer does happen to be trying to make a duplicate payment attempt for such a # that has already resulted in a successful transaction on your PayPal account before, it will be blocked by default (according to your PayPal account settings)